# CSS3 gradient on full background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a CSS gradient as a full background, but when I use jQuery for the drop down menu, the background shows repeating.

These are the body properties:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: #639964; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%, #402180 94%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(25%,#639964), color-stop(94%,#402180)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#639964', endColorstr='#402180',GradientType=1); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have put the full code in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNxBLE).

Please, could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below at end after all the background properties and it should work fine.

```
background-attachment: fixed;

body {
height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background: #639964; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%, #402180 94%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(25%,#639964), color-stop(94%,#402180)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#639964', endColorstr='#402180',GradientType=1); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
margin: 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: That's it! It's the most simple way to get it. But I can't understand why the order where I put that line makes this change.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a new fixed position div with 100% width and 100% height. Apply the gradient background here instead in your body tag.

put this div at the very first of your body tag.

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wehpogi. It works, but there is no scroll bar on the page when the menu gets larger: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azqoYd

Answer (score 0):

add in body part

#### css

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#639964), to(#402180)) fixed;
```

second way

#### css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
    background: linear-gradient( to left top, blue, red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 background: linear-gradient(90deg,  #639964 25%,#402180 94%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hager Aly, it works, but I need (want) a diagonal gradient.